# Merge Sort and term definitions

Tags: java, sorting, merge

So I have this homework that says:

"b) Use merge sort to sort the values in the table below.  Show each recursive call and merge on a separate line. You do not need to show individual swaps, since a second array would be used to perform this task. When there are an equal number of values in the right and left halves, assume that the right half contains the larger number of values. The Step column should contain RRC (right recursive call), LRC (left recursive call), or M (merge)."
and shows me a table with a first column for the "Step" and the rest of the columns is one space for each number in the array or sequence. The table has a big number of rows so that I can fill in each row the steps for the sorting. [Yeah I'm a noob, I don't know how to make tables on this text editing tool.]

My problem at this homework is that I have no clue whatsoever what the professor meant by "Left recursive call" or "Right recursive call" and for that "Merge" either. **I know how to do the Merge sort.** The only thing I don't know are these terms that I have to use to fill in the first column of each row.

I really need help, there is no where in the web where this is explained.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'left recursive' and 'right recursive' means the part of the mergesort algorithm where you call sort on the left and right halves of the list. Merge should be obvious if you know the mergesort algorithm. (also, can't you ask your professor?)

Comment: Yeah... but like, it's night right now and pretty much tomorrow I will be very busy and I will only be able to submit the homework.

Answer (score 0):

[Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_Sort) is a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) algorithm, and one that works by splitting a list (or table, or array, or whathaveyou) into approximately equal lengths.

So, since you split your list of values into two parts, one can be considered the Left part, and one can be considered the Right part.  You then sort each of those recursively.

Can you now figure out what LRC and RRC refer to?

Comment: So say I have 192837465.
I divide this in multiples arrays through recursion and then I finally get to the array "1 9"
If I sort that one, would it be LRC or RRC?
later on when I am into merging 19 and 28, would that be M (merge) or RRC or LRC or all of them?
That is what confuses me.

Comment: In [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Merge-sort-example-300px.gif) whenever red is happening, it's a Merge.  Otherwise, it's either an RRC or an LRC based on which side it's on.  Also study [a human's simulated steps for Merge Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg).